# How to draw boxes around "groups" in a heatmap?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I made a graph like this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

m <- matrix(1:64 - 32, 8)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <-
  c(paste0("a", 1:3), paste0("b", 1:2), paste0("c", 1:3))
d <- melt(m)
gg <- ggplot(d) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2()
```

How can I programmatically draw boxes around the "a", "b", and "c" groups?

The matrix `m` will always be square. `colnames(m)` and `rownames(m)` will always be the same. Therefore the boxes will be cover the entire grid and will never overlap. The group sizes will vary, in general.

I'm also not married to `ggplot2`. I'm open to a solution in base graphics with `image` if it's not fussier than the `ggplot2`/`grid` version.

I got as far as

```
d$group <- substr(d$Var1, 1, 1)
```

before I realized I had no clue how to proceed.

---

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do this with `geom_rect`.

Comment: @Roland that's what I was thinking. The issue is how to identify the boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be considered cheating, but very easy:

```
# Depending on your data you may be able to generate `d2` directly
# here we need to re-order a bit

d2 <- transform(
   d, V1 = substr(Var1, 1, 1), 
   V2=factor(substr(Var2, 1, 1), levels=letters[3:1])
)
ggplot(d2) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2() +
  facet_grid(V2 ~ V1, scales="free", space="free")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. It might turn out ugly in my case, though.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, you should be able to mess with the formatting a bit to make it cleaner if needed; the main point is that here you use `ggplot` to compute the coordinates for you.

Comment: It actually came out looking very nice!

Comment: Just pointing out something essential that you include here but don't explicitly talk about: the order of the facets is reversed relative to the order of the axes.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, do you mean the need to re-order the levels of V2?

Comment: Yes exactly. Caught me off guard at first

Answer (score 6):

Or `geom_segment`

```
library('reshape2')
library('ggplot2')

m <- matrix(1:64 - 32, 8)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <-
  c(paste0("a", 1:3), paste0("b", 1:2), paste0("c", 1:3))
gg <- ggplot(melt(m)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2()

tt <- table(gsub('\\d+', '', colnames(m)))
ll <- unname(c(0, cumsum(tt)) + .5)

gg + geom_segment(aes(x = ll, xend = ll, y = head(ll, 1), yend = tail(ll, 1))) + 
  geom_segment(aes(y = ll, yend = ll, x = head(ll, 1), xend = tail(ll, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'll' not found`. It seems like it _ought_ to work, but I'm using it inside another function and I know `ggplot2` scoping can be bizarre.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of. I'll do some debugging and accept this answer when I can get it to work.

Comment: Confirmed: the caveat is that this only works at the top level unless `plot` or `print` itself is called inside the function; if the `gg` object is returned to another scope/environment it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

i.e. something like this:

```
xmin <- c(0.5,3.5,5.5)
xmax <- c(3.5,5.5,8.5)
ymin <- c(0.5,3.5,5.5)
ymax <- c(3.5,5.5,8.5)
box1 <- data.frame(xmin = rep(xmin,times = 3),
                   xmax = rep(xmax,each = 3),
                   ymin = rep(ymin,times = 3),
                   ymax = rep(ymax,each = 3))
ggplot(melt(m)) +
    geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
    geom_rect(data = box1,aes(xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax,ymin = ymin,ymax= ymax),
                        fill = NA,color = "black") +
    scale_fill_gradient2()
```

Another option would be to simply use `geom_hline` and `geom_vline`, although you might have a hard time removing the little bits that extend past the edges of the colored rectangles.

Comment: The whole point is to not have to hard-code the coordinates. My real data is much bigger.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Doing the groups programmatically is a whole other question, which will depend strongly on the specific constraints of your data. How many groups can there be? Will they always be in a certain order? Will the boxes always be defined by intersections of single axis groups, or multiple? I hard coded the coordinates in my answer because there's no way to write that code for you without knowing the specifics of your problem. And it would be much more complicated.

Comment: ...that's why I asked the question